# Type aliasing a case class in Scala 2.10

Tags: scala

I'm using Scala 2.10.2, and have two case classes that have identical fields:

```
case class Foo(id: String, name: String)
case class Bar(id: String, name: String)
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
case class Thing(id: String, name: String)
type Foo = Thing
type Bar = Thing
```

This compiles, but when I try to create a `Foo`, I get:

```
scala> Bar("a", "b")
<console>:8: error: not found: value Bar
              Bar("a", "b")
              ^
```

Does type aliasing not work with case classes?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you create a case class Scala automatically creates a companion object for it. In your code you define an alias for the type `Thing`, i.e. for the class `Thing` only. Your companion object `Thing` still has only 1 name and no aliases.

One way to "fix" it is to create a reference to the companion object (not a type alias) like this:

```
scala> val Bar = Thing
Bar: Thing.type = Thing

scala> Bar("a", "b")
res1: Thing = Thing(a,b)
```

Another way to "fix" it would be to rename the imported object with `import package.{Thing => Bar}`.

Comment: `val Bar = Thing` this will add an object alias instead of a type alias

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov I'd still say "to create a reference to the companion object _together with_ a type alias".

Answer (score 5):

Type aliases only alias the type, not any companion object that might be supplying factory methods (whether you write that factory method yourself or get one "for free" from the compiler).

On the other hand, importing acts on names and if there are multiple entities associated with a given name, importing that name brings in every referent of the imported name. Additionally, you can rename when importing and you can do so multiply, so...

```
scala> object Stuff { case class Thing(id: String, name: String) }
defined module Stuff


scala> import Stuff.Thing
import Stuff.Thing

scala> import Stuff.{Thing => Foo}
import Stuff.{Thing=>Foo}

scala> import Stuff.{Thing => Bar}
import Stuff.{Thing=>Bar}


scala> val thing1 = Thing("fing", "fang")
thing1: Stuff.Thing = Thing(fing,fang)

scala> val foo1 = Foo("yes", "no")
foo1: Stuff.Thing = Thing(yes,no)

scala> val bar1 = Bar("true", "false")
bar1: Stuff.Thing = Thing(true,false)
```

It's no good for the rendering via `toString`, though, as you can see.

Answer (score 4):

```
case class Thing(id: String, name: String)
type Foo = Thing
type Bar = Thing
```

if you say `new Bar("a","b")` it will work

Answer (score 0):

Do you want `Foo` and `Bar` to be distinguishable (as when they are different case classes) or not? If yes, and you just want to avoid repeating list of fields, you can do this:

```
case class Foo(thing: Thing)
case class Bar(thing: Thing)
```

But this will obviously make them a bit less convenient to use in pattern matching or access fields. Field access can be improved a bit:

```
trait ThingWrapper {
  def thing: Thing
  def id = thing.id
  def name = thing.name
}

case class Foo(thing: Thing) extends ThingWrapper
case class Bar(thing: Thing) extends ThingWrapper
```